# Featured Image not showing in admin

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development, customization

Currently im making new theme and had the idea of adding featured image in the admin side of wordpress, unfortunately its not working this is what i have tried

I have added this code in functions.php

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails');
```

i also tried to change it

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails', array( 'post' ) ); // Add it for posts
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails', array( 'page' ) ); // Add it for pages
```

after i refresh and log in to my admin panel and tried to create new post or page 
featured image is not displaying and

after my set up function which is ja_theme_setup this is my code

```
add_action('after-setup_theme','ja_theme_setup' );
```

and also i have tried to look at **SCREEN OPTIONS** but i dont have any availble checkbox related to featured image..Please help me guys

**NOTE:** 
My wp-config.php file debug options is set to true

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
```

and yet i dont have any errors

Comment: Are you using [`after_setup_theme`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/after_setup_theme) action?

Comment: yes after my setup function it do this since my function name is ja_theme_setup
add_action('after-setup_theme','ja_theme_setup' );

Comment: In that case, your code looks OK should work. Sorry, imposible to know wath is happening without a deeper investigation into your site. Try to disable all plugins to check if the problem is from some plugin or from your theme, so you can narrow down the source of the problem.

Comment: I've noticed a error in the action name, see my answer.

Comment: actually i dont have any plugin enable

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have misspelled the action hook name.

This:

```
add_action( 'after-setup_theme', 'ja_theme_setup' );
```

Should be:

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'ja_theme_setup' );
```

The full code:

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'ja_theme_setup' );
function ja_theme_setup() {
    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to go your wp-admin/post/ top right corner show "**screen Options**" click on this and

expand screen-option then click on **Featured Image** check box

Hope this help you..

Comment: i am not say you want add but just click on check box to show feature image in admin side.. have you got it ???

Answer (score -1):

Your code should work , but as it is not working the try the following things

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails');
```

Just put this code in `functions.php`  , not within a function . Just put this code on the top of your `functions.php` file .  If it is not working  then try this plugin

[Drag & Drop Featured Image](https://wordpress.org/plugins/drag-drop-featured-image/)

Comment: So are you saying that your functions.php already have that code , and then you have write it one more time inside your ja_theme_setup functions ? 

If it is true , then please remove any one of this either the code in functions.php or in your ja_theme_setup functions

Comment: in your answer you said that i will put this add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails'); to functions.php file . what im saying is its already in the functions.php file not in any other file . please read my question carefully

Comment: It might be caching issue then , please try change your theme , after that reactivate your custom theme . Hope it works